# Rotate rectangle with math

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, rotation

I want to rotate rectangle like this:

[image]

I don't want to use `save()`, `translate()`, `rotate()` and `restore()`. I want to use simple math to do it. Here is an example what I did already:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grcbab4h/2/)

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically need to calculate each corner and draw the rectangle using `.lineTo()` instead of `.fillRect()`.

To rotate a point around origin by angle you need this:

```
var rotate = function( point, origin, angle) {
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return {
        x: Math.cos(angle) * (point.x-origin.x) - Math.sin(angle) * (point.y -origin.y) + origin.x,
        y: Math.sin(angle) * (point.x-origin.x) + Math.cos(angle) * (point.y-origin.y) + origin.y
    };
}
```

Then define your rectangle corners:

```
 var corners = [
        { x: 100, y: 0 },
        { x: 150, y: 0 },
        { x: 150, y: 50 },
        { x: 100, y: 50 }
    ];
```

And render it like this:

```
    // for example: 
    // origin = { x: 125, y: 175 }, angle = 30;
    ctx.beginPath();
    corners.forEach( function( point ){
        var rotated = rotate( point, origin, angle );
        ctx.lineTo( rotated.x, rotated.y );
    });
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grcbab4h/3/